# Google Cloud Loud Balancer SSL Handshake failure

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, https, load-balancing

I have set up a Google Cloud Http(s) Load Balancer with Frontend of Https and Backend of Http. I am getting the following error through Postman for my service:

Error: write EPROTO 140566936757448:error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:594:SSL alert number 40 140566936757448:error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.cc:603:

The VM itself works if I call it directly with Http. Is this setup possible or what am I missing?

Comment: Have a look at this [similar issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8612) which got registered in github for more detailed information .

Answer (score 1):

[SSLV3 is not supported by HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-policies-concepts#defining_an_ssl_policy). Please, use a newer (and more secure) version to call your HTTPS load balancer

Comment: I was using Postman when I got that error

Comment: Yes,, maybe update it? Maybe change the configuration of Postman.

Comment: @JamesAnderbard Postman is using the SSL layer from your web browser. Your solution is to update your browser or update the OS. Upgrading both might be required. However, your question does not specify your environment.

Comment: I figured out that the issue was that the certificate hadn't been validated yet and once that was fixed it started working.